# I get an error when there is another tx record related to the target token in the same block

Tags: blockchain, transactions, nodejs, bsc, pending-transactions

I create a smart contract and interact with node.js and buy and sell a token.
Here is part of my smart contract:

```
// TokenBuy Function ->
function buyToken(address token, uint amountOutMin, uint deadline) public payable  {
address[] memory path = new address[](2);
path[0] = WBNB;
path[1] = token;

pancakeRouter.swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(
amountOutMin,
path,
address(this),
deadline
);
}

// TokenSell Function ->
function sellAllTokens(address token, uint amountOutMin, uint deadline) public  {
uint tokenAmount = IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));

IERC20(token).approve(address(pancakeRouter), tokenAmount);

address[] memory path = new address[](2);
path[0] = token;
path[1] = WBNB;

pancakeRouter.swapExactTokensForETH(
tokenAmount,
amountOutMin,
path,
msg.sender,
deadline
);
}
```

The "buyToken" and "sellAllTokens" functions here buy an amount from the token address I sent with node.js and sell it back.

Part of my Node.js code is as follows;

```
async function getNonce() {
    return await wallet.getTransactionCount(); }
async function buyToken(tokenAddress, bnbAmount, nonce) {
    const options = {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther(bnbAmount.toString()),
        gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('4', 'gwei'),
        gasLimit: 250000,
        nonce: nonce
    };

    return contract.Ox5(tokenAddress, 0, Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 120, options); }

async function sellAllTokensAfterBuy(tokenAddress, nonce) {
    const options = {
        gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('3', 'gwei'),
        gasLimit: 250000,
        nonce: nonce
    };

    return contract.Ox6(tokenAddress, 0, Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 120, options); }

async function executeTransactions(tokenAddress, bnbAmount) {
      const nonce = await getNonce();
    const buyTx = await buyToken(tokenAddress, bnbAmount, nonce);
    console.log('Buy Transaction hash:', buyTx.hash);

    const sellTx = await sellAllTokensAfterBuy(tokenAddress, nonce + 1);
    console.log('Sell Transaction hash:', sellTx.hash);
}

const tokenAddress = '0x..........';
const bnbAmount = 0.00001;
executeTransactions(tokenAddress, bnbAmount)
    .then(receipts => console.log("Transaction successful:", receipts))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

However, when a tx record other than the token I traded enters between my buying and selling transaction, the following errors usually occur in the tx record of the selling transaction;

"Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'"

"Fail with error 'Pancake: K'"

"Fail with error 'PancakeRouter: EXPIRED'"

"Fail with error 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT'"

These errors occur if there is another tx record related to the target token between my purchase and sale transaction in the block where I buy and sell.

**For example;**

My purchase transaction (Token target: x) -> Block index: 26

My sales transaction (Token target: x)-> Block index: 79

This way, I do not receive any errors and the buying and selling transactions are completed successfully.

**For example;**

My purchase transaction (Token target: x) -> Block index: 26

Someone else's purchase transaction (Token target: x) -> Block index: 43

My sales transaction (Token target: x)-> Block index: 79

This is how the errors I mentioned above occur.

Can anyone help me know how to fix this?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution, maybe someone knows something about this issue.